# Setting and Getting Image Attribute Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to Getting and Setting Image Attibute using javascript in HTML,

it's like generate image HTML Element using Javascript ?

anyone can help me ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Can you help us to help you first? Tell us more about what you want to do. What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: I am update my answer , sorry for bad my english  I am new in stackoverflow and javascript, I hope with new update you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomended to read Documentation first.

```
var image = document.images[0];
var width = parseInt(image.getAttribute('WIDTH')); //for get attribute width of image
image.setAttribute("class","thumbnail"); //for setting attribute class of Image
```

here the documentation attributes of image

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement